# Cannot create node group via sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-eks

I am trying to create a nodegroup via the aws sdk for node.js I'd prefer to do this than via the eksctl.

This is a simple question but there are just no code examples of this in the aws docs and I can't figure out the correct name spaces so unfortunately I am asking here:

My code is as follows with node.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

const eks = new AWS.EKS();

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

// Name must be cluster

eks.CreateNodegroup({name:'openstudio-server',
    instanceTypes:["t2.xlarge"],
    "nodegroupName":'openstudio-node',   
    "scalingConfig": { 
      "desiredSize": 3,
      "maxSize": 10,
      "minSize": 3
   }
   })
```

I am consistently getting the error

[image: TypeError: eks.CreateNodegroup is not a f]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've resolved this already but it looks like you just need to change `eks.CreateNodegroup()` to `eks.createNodegroup()` and it should work.

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EKS.html